# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable on line 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am really new to Python so i was going through the interactive guide on runestone and entered this code:

```
t = int(input("number of yrs plsz"))
a = 10000(1+(0.08/12))**12t
print(a)
```

I am receiving this error

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable on line 2

Comment: Why have you tagged this with both `python-2.7` and `python-3.x`? It's not really relevant to the part you're asking about, but your code will do different things on the two versions, because `input` is a different function. Also, unless you specifically need something that's compatible with both, you shouldn't tag it with both.

Comment: i am sorry, i didn't really know there was any difference and i wanted to get more response. i will keep note of that, Thank you

Comment: "I wanted to get more response" is a bad idea to add more tags. Add tags that are relevant to your question. Trying to drag in people who don't actually care about your problem but do care about one of your tags is just a way to collect downvotes.

Comment: You may consider fixing it :-) Which version are you speaking of?

Answer (score 2):

`10000()` is syntax for calling a function (`myfunction()`). Instead, multiply with the `*` operator.

By using the parentheses, you are attempting to call the function `10000` which cannot be done because `10000` is an integer, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't multiply with parentheses, you need to explicitly type all the multiplication operators like so:

```
a = 10000 * (1 + (0.08 / 12)) ** (12 * t) # basically you can't call 10000() as a func
```

Comment: Edited, because I'm pretty sure "You can multiply with parentheses" was just a typo.

Comment: `f(a)` where `f` and `a` are both integers is not valid in Python.

Comment: @abarnert You know what I mean (;

Comment: Yes, that's why I edited to what I was pretty sure you meant instead of commenting that this was wrong or downvoting or something. :)

Comment: Yeah, at first I was like: What did he even change?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the notation you're using on line 2.

When you write a = 1000(something), python thinks you're trying to call the method named "1000".

Rewrite as

a = 10000 * (1+(0.08/12))**12t)

Also I assume you're trying to do 12*t, you cannot just say 12t. Thats invalid syntax as well.

So really should be

```
a = 10000 * (1+(0.08/12))**12*t
```

I'm not sure on the math aspect of re-writing it this way, but at least it will run.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanted to write is:

```
a = 10000 * (1 + (0.08 / 12)) ** (12 * t)
```

This will work like a charm, but the origin of the error might confuse you. The problem is that as soon as Python sees a parenthesis after any object, say

```
obj(p1)
```

it makes a call to the object's `__call__` method like this

```
obj.__call__(p1)
```

If it is not defined you get the error you had. So what happened in your code is that Python reached the part `a = 10000(...`, it tried to do something like this

```
10000.__call__(1 + (0.08 / 12))
```

as `10000` is an instance of `int` class, it tried to find definition of `__call__` method for that class. As you would guess, `int` class does not define `__call__` method, thus the error.

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
a = 10000*(1+(0.08/12))**12*t.
```

If you are multiplying t to 12, put bracket.

Comment: `12t` is just invalid syntax, `10000(arg)` is `'int' object is not callable`

Comment: What does "If you are multiplying t to 12, put bracket" mean? It sounds like you're suggesting that he should use round brackets for the last multiplication, exactly as he tried to for the first, which will have exactly the same problem.

Comment: I am suggesting that if he wanted t in exponent then he could have put (12*t), which seems obvious.

Comment: i think he meant **(12*t) ?